# Update the value in mysql PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am unable to update the value in the mySQL table.  In my code below, `option` is in the format of `[["test",0],["opt",0]]`.  I want to update it to `[["test",1],["opt",0]]`

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{ 
$opt=$_POST['xyz'];
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("test"); 
 $sqlstmt="select * from polls where question='".$_POST['name']."' ";
$abc = mysql_query($sqlstmt); 
$rw=mysql_fetch_array($abc);
$opts = json_decode($rw['option']);


 for($i=0;$i<sizeof($opts);$i++)
 {
//$sqlstmt="select * from polls where question='".$_POST['name']."' and opton=$opt";

   if($opt==$opts[$i][0])
   {
  $opts[$i][1]+=1;
  echo $opts[$i][1];

    }

}
var_dump($opts);

$a=json_encode($opts);
  $b="UPDATE  polls
  SET option="$a", 
  WHERE question='".$_POST['name']."'";
  var_dump($_POST['name']);
  $c=mysql_query($b);
 var_dump($c);
}
```

I don't know where I am going wrong but `var_dump($c)` is returning the boolean `false`

Comment: why are you json_decoding $rw[option], is it json data saved into the database?

Comment: Yes Kylek it is storing in the form of json data like [["test",0],["opt",0]]

Comment: You forgot concatenation around `$a`.

Comment: Does this code actually compile? Also, your code is vulnerable to [sql injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1).

Comment: this code is compiling and the value is also updating but it is ubnable to update in database

Comment: Your code gives a parse error, as can be seen [here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/rfUhxn).

Comment: Ive provided you complete PDO code, check below

Comment: You are using [an **obsolete** database API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/19068) and should use a [modern replacement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php).  You are also **vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com/)** that a modern API would make it easier to [defend](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) yourself from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off..
You should be using PDO instead of the deprecated mysql_* functions please...
Your code has major security holes!!!

http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

But, to answer you question...your problem is concatenation of $a
So just change to this...

```
$a=json_encode($opts);
$b="UPDATE  polls SET option='".$a."' 
WHERE question='".$_POST['name']."'";
$c=mysql_query($b);
var_dump($c);
}
```

**UPDATE / EDIT**
Heres your complete code, with PDO, for safety

You have to edit your connection info obviously, and I haven't tested this, but PDO is better than deprecated mysql_* functions, so here you go...

```
$dbname = "test";
$hostname = "localhost";
$pw = "root";
$username = "";

if (isset($_POST['submit']))
  { 
   $opt=$_POST['xyz'];

  $pdo = new PDO ("mssql:host=$hostname;dbname=$dbname","$username","$pw");
  try{
  $query = $pdo->prepare("select * from polls where question=:question");
  $query->execute(array(':question' => $_POST['name']));
  $rw = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  } catch(PDOException $ex) {
  //whatever error handling you want
  echo "An Error occured!"; 
  some_logging_function($ex->getMessage());
  }

  $opts = json_decode($rw['option']);

  for($i=0;$i<sizeof($opts);$i++)
  {
   if($opt==$opts[$i][0])
  {
  $opts[$i][1]+=1;

}

$a=json_encode($opts);
try { 
$query = $pdo->prepare("UPDATE  polls
SET option=? WHERE question=?");
$query->execute(array($a, $_POST['name']));
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
  //whatever error handling you want
  echo "An Error occured!"; 
  some_logging_function($ex->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: This code is dangerous, because there's no sql injection mitigation done.

Comment: well obviously....were fixing his problems, not security holes

Comment: You should write code as if it's going to be copied and pasted into production code; this might actually be true in some cases. Adding a simple `mysql_real_escape_string()` would be the minimum.

Comment: +1 for substantially improving the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues; the most important one is having vulnerable code:

```
$sqlstmt="select * from polls where question='".$_POST['name']."' ";
```

This is dangerous code, because it opens up the code for [SQL injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1). The least you should do is escape any user input:

```
$sqlstmt = sprintf("select * from polls where question='%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])
);
```

Furthermore, the update statement has a parse error in both PHP *and* MySQL. Here's the fix:

```
$b = sprintf("UPDATE polls SET `option`='%s' WHERE question='%s'",
    mysql_real_escape_string($a),
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name'])
);
```

Note that `option` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) in MySQL and therefore must be enclosed by backticks.

**Recommendation**

I would recommend you read up on either [mysqli](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) and adopt prepared statements as the way to prevent the most common SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thank you jack i am a begginer il try to implement what u have said

Comment: jack it is not updating into database

Comment: Jack i already used die(mysql_error()) but it is showing 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'option='[[\"Option1\",1],[\"Option2\",0],[\"Option3\",0],[\"Option4\",0]]' WHERE' at line 1

Comment: should i use while loop?

Comment: @ShashankCool Oh, guess `option` is a reserved word, so you need to escape that with backticks .. updated answer.

Comment: jack still it is not working :(

Comment: yea jack the same error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''option'='[[\"Option1\",1],[\"Option2\",0],[\"Option3\",0],[\"Option4\",0]]' WHERE' at line 1

Comment: @ShashankCool I don't see the backticks around `option` ... backticks are not normal ticks, if you're not sure, copy and paste from my answer.

Answer (score -1):

Change -

```
  $b="UPDATE  polls
  SET option="$a", 
  WHERE question='".$_POST['name']."'";
```

**To**

```
$b="UPDATE  polls SET option='".$a."' WHERE question='".$_POST['name']."'";
```

As per the [JACK](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1338292/jack) suggestion..the above code is open to SQL injections..so take of it before implementing it in real terms.

[Read well popular post here to deal with the sql injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Reason for doing this so ?

Comment: Yeah I got downvoted to....dont understand the reason...our answers are completely valid